# Combining a matrix of numbers, with array of strings

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, numbers

I am trying to compute the code seen below, in a more clever way, using MatLAB:

```
f=zeros(5,2) %Values irrelevant.
y = {'A1', 'B1'; 
     f(1,1) f(1,2); 
     f(2,1) f(2,2); 
     f(3,1) f(3,2); 
     f(4,1) f(4,2); 
     f(5,1) f(5,2)};
```

What I get out is the `f` matrix with the text of `A1` and `B1` above the two vectors.

I suppose there is a simpler way to write this, for more complex purposing, but I've tried any combination of parenthesis, brackets and curly brackets, `num2str` that I could think of.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) and concatenate the result with the strings:

```
y = [{'A1', 'B1'}; num2cell(f)];
```

#### Example

```
>> f = reshape(1:10, 2, [])';
>> y = [{'A1', 'B1'}; num2cell(f)]

y =
    'A1'    'B1'
    [ 1]    [ 2]
    [ 3]    [ 4]
    [ 5]    [ 6]
    [ 7]    [ 8]
    [ 9]    [10]
```

Comment: Flawless.I'll keep the num2cell function in mind.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Glad to help. By the way, a more general function is [`'mat2cell'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html), which might also be helpful.

Comment: Knowledge of how MATLAB performs indexing would also help here. Instead of listing out `f(1,2), f(2,2), f(3,2)`, etc, you can write `f(:,2)`